# Conditionally evaulate a condition SQL

Tags: sql, db2, case, sybase, case-when

I have an employee table from which I retrieve records using a stored procedure now I need to add a condition in the stored procedure --

Only if employeeType='MD' then check if employeeReportableIndicator='N' , if 'N' then do not fetch this record.

This implicitly means --

1)if employeeType!='MD' then I should fetch the record regardless of employeeReportableIndicator column value .

2)if employeeType='MD' and employeeReportableIndicator='Y' fetch the value .

To simplify the stored procedure I am just writing a small query covering the above condition .Here is what I tried till now

```
select * 
from   employee 
where  somecondition1 
and    somecondition2 
and    CASE when employeeType='MD' 
            then (CASE when employeeReportableIndicator='N' 
                       then false 
                       else true 
                  END) 
       END
```

The above is giving me syntax error

> an unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "else true END ) END".Expected token may include: "".SQLSTATE=42601

Also is my approach for writing the query correct ,please suggest if any better solution. I am using DB2 and Sybase

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `CASE` for this, just an `OR` condition:

```
Select  *
From    Employee
Where   SomeCondition1
And     SomeCondition2
And     
(   
    EmployeeType <> 'MD'
    Or  
    (   
        EmployeeType = 'MD'
    And EmployeeReportableIndicator = 'Y'
    )
)
```

Comment: Can be simplified.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Care to elaborate?  Even if it can be simplified somehow, the intent is perfectly clear as written.

Comment: There are four possible cases for the last conditions: MD+Y, MD+N, !MD+Y, !MD+Y.  If !MD, we consider the condition fulfilled (don't care about Y/N), which eliminates half the table.  This leaves just MD+Y and MD+N... where the only distinct part is Y/N.  At that point, checking whether MD is frivolous, thus: `AND employeeType <> 'MD' OR employeeReportableIndicator = 'Y'`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a case when you shoul use  an AND -  OR in where

```
select * 
from   employee 
where  somecondition1 
and    somecondition2 
and    ( ( employeeType='MD' AND employeeReportableIndicator='Y') 
           OR ( employeeType!='MD ))
```

Comment: Can be simplified.